# TSQL: Combining records within a single table based on time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains time-stamped data. Data values are measured in different reference frames, and so in the example below A is being measured by B, but B is being measured by C. I can estimate what A would have been if measured by C by looking up the values of A->B and B->C  for the same timestamp, and adding them together. I have been trying to write a query that takes each A->B measurement, looks up the nearest B->C measurement, and returns TimestampA, ValueA, TimestampB, ValueB , Value A+B. Can anyone help?

```
TimeStamp       ID  ParentID    Value  
19:44:04.877    A   B           176.5429  
19:44:04.877    A   B           176.2653  
19:44:09.893    A   B           170.5266  
19:44:09.893    A   B           170.883  
19:44:14.887    A   B           164.3122  
19:44:14.887    A   B           164.1429  
19:44:19.880    A   B           158.5632  
19:44:19.880    A   B           158.1787  
19:44:24.870    A   B           153.0709  
19:44:24.870    A   B           152.8471  
19:44:00.403    B   C           195184.2  
19:44:05.443    B   C           195189.8  
19:44:10.450    B   C           195195.4  
19:44:15.487    B   C           195201.3  
19:44:20.523    B   C           195207.2  
19:44:25.570    B   C           195212.6
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: Perhaps this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7ae2/5/0

Comment: Does that have to be done in the database? It looks more like a business logic task.

Comment: I am new to this site, and so apologies for such a poor question, I will try to do better next time. Tim's answer is perfect, but I cannot see how to mark it as having fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `LEFT JOIN` the table with itself, have a look:

```
SELECT  this.TimeStamp AS [this TimeStamp], 
        this.Value AS [this Value], 
        parent.Timestamp AS [parent Timestamp], 
        parent.Value AS [parent Value], 
        this.Value + ISNULL(parent.Value, 0) AS [Total Value]
FROM dbo.TableName this
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TableName parent
  ON  this.ParentID = parent.ID
  AND parent.Value = (SELECT MIN(Value)FROM dbo.TableName p
                      WHERE p.ID = this.ParentID
                      AND p.Value >= this.Value)
```

[**Here's a demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7ae2/5/0).